# Reading binary files

Tags: .net, visual-c++

Although I suspect I know the answer, I will be interested in people's responses.

Currently, I have a VC6 app running on W2K3 that reads a text file using the following(simplified code):

```
string line;
ifstream infile("test.txt",ios::in);
while (!infile.eof())
{
   getline(infile,line);
}
...
```

Each record in the file has fields that are pipe delimited and the code works fine thanks to CRLF, although fields and records are not fixed length.  The issue now is that the file is going to be binary due to some data being unsigned packed decimal in addition to text.  Basically, is the code above still valid if opened as a binary file(delimiters and LF retained)?  I tried a quick test with some dummy data and it appeared to behave the same.

It is my understanding that binary files are read w/the knowledge of data content so the bytes can be properly retrieved and w/o LF's.  I've searched around the web and found various options for C++ and other .NET languages(an option), but none seem capable of reading one line at a time -- even if the variable sized data and LF seem to defeat the purpose of using a binary file -- and I do not want to read the entire file in one shot since it could be quite large(hoping not to read one char at a time either).

So if the above might be valid, is there a risk of data loss?  If it is not, other options would be appreciated.  And if I am missing something here, please feel free to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on rows being limited by CRLF then if the binary data has CRLF you'll get a false line break. Also, if the binary data contains a the value 124 (vertical pipe) you'll have issues determining columns.

Comment: Agreed, but assume the LF and pipes are not part of the "data" so they can be used as field and line separators.

Comment: I haven't worked in a packed decimal format in a long while but can you actually guarantee that you'll never have the byte sequences `0000 1101`, `0000 1010` or `0111 1100` written? `getline` will be looking for one or both of the first two (depending on what you call it with) and your split algorithm will be looking for the last.

Comment: I'm not a C guy so I don't know `getline` too well but in C#/VB we'd use a `StreamReader` to read the file as text and when you do you tell it what encoding (ASCII/UTF8/etc) it should use to parse the raw bytes with. As long as the encoding supports the bytes read you can work with the string. Make sure you're aware of the encoding. ASCII will be 1 byte/character but UT8 could be 1 to 6 bytes/character.